# Find last row/column visible for a page layout

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI 4.1.1, and I am trying to identify the rows/columns that would fit on a page as if viewed in Excel page layout view. Is there any way to do it? I've tried using `Sheet.getLastRowNum()` method, but that doesn't always get me the correct results.
I made a screenshot of what I am trying to accomplish.
[Example image to illustrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JahY4.png)
Result for my example image would be: last row ist '27' and the last column is 'J'

Comment: There is [`Workbook.getPrintArea()`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#getPrintArea-int-) which returns a `String`. Don't know the format, but I think it could be like `A1:J27` and you can `split(":")` it in order to get last row and colum...

Comment: @deHaar I've tried that but it returns null

Comment: Well, it *returns `null` if no print area is set*... Maybe set one yourself before? Don't know if that helps, but I don't have any other idea.

Comment: I am so sorry... somehow I did not set the area (or saved the file) :( - If set, the format is something like 'Tabelle1!$A$1:$G$48'. Thank you!

Comment: Hehe... No problem! There could have been a default print area, but the one your image shows doesn't look *default*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Workbook.getPrintArea()` [javadoc](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#getPrintArea-int-) as mentioned by deHaar helped me out.